# php session fails on first attempt if server has been idle

Tags: php, session

For some reason the first login attempt will fail if the server has been idle for some time, for example a couple of hours.

This is what happens:

1. The user navigates to a login script
2. The script sets session variables and redirects to the main page
3. The main page should be able to read the session variable (but fails in this case)

There are no remarks in the PHP error log and the second attempt works fine. It only happens for the first user accessing the page after a idle period. For example if another user tries to log in 5 seconds later, everything works fine.

This is on a IIS7 with PHP 5.3 using FastCGI.

Any ideas what's wrong here or what I can do to find a solution?

This is roughly how the scripts are set up
login.php:

```
@session_start();
$_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;
session_write_close();
session_unset();
usleep(200000);     
header('Location:index.php');
```

main script

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
   // Login successful
}
```

Comment: I can only say, check your code. If you can paste your code, we can check it for you.

Comment: I agree with @AbhishekSaha. But what I understand so far, you might want to check if your session is properly started consistently with `session_start();` on every page you need sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the three lines.

```
session_write_close();
session_unset();
sleep(200000);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try. Do you have a theory on why these lines would cause a problem and why only for the first login attempt?

Comment: Well, session_write_close doesn't allow you to write further sessions. Unset will remove all session variables. Sleep works but you need to use carefully. I am typing from cellphone so not able to explain everything. Will write in detail later at night.